# Getting the size of the __TEXT section at link time on macOS

Tags: c, macos, linker, darwin, mach-o

With `gold` and other linkers, it's possible to have the linker write the start/end of the `.text` section into the binary as constants using a linker script, e.g.

```
PROVIDE_HIDDEN(linker_script_start_of_text = ADDR(.text));
PROVIDE_HIDDEN(linker_script_end_of_text = ADDR(.text) + SIZEOF(.text));
```

linked with `ld -Tmy_linker_script.lds ...`.

I know it's possible to call [getsectdata](https://opensource.apple.com/source/cctools/cctools-751/include/mach-o/getsect.h.auto.html) or similar to get information about the `.text` section or parse it from the mach-o header, but is there a way to have the linker insert this data as a constant?

Answer (score 7):

You can get the Darwin linker to insert this data with a bit of trickery using `__asm`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int start_text __asm("section$start$__TEXT$__text");
extern int end_text __asm("section$end$__TEXT$__text");

int main() {
  size_t text_section_size_bytes =
    (intptr_t)&end_text - (intptr_t)&start_text;

  printf("__TEXT.__text section size: 0x%lx\n", text_section_size_bytes);

  return 0;
}
```

On my machine, this prints:

```
$ clang -o test ./test.c
$ ./test
__TEXT.__text section size: 0x43
```

Which matches up with what `objdump` reports:

```
$ objdump -h ./test
./foo2: file format Mach-O 64-bit x86-64

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      Address          Type
  0 __text        00000043 0000000100000f30 TEXT
  [...]
```

You can also do the same trick to get the size of whole *segments* (as opposed to sections) by using the syntax `segment$start$__TEXT` / `segment$end$__TEXT`.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere? If not, what part of the linker source code does this?

Comment: It is not documented. There's a unit test for it in the linker code though: https://github.com/apple-opensource-mirror/ld64/blob/9a22e880dba9ffe644cf5479d410d82a70c36b06/unit-tests/test-cases/segment-labels/main.c#L29